# numpy.array converts integers in my list into str_: ()

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a list of lists. Each list contains of both `str` and `int`:

```
[38, 'Private', 89814, 'HS-grad', 9, 'Married-civ-spouse', 'Farming-fishing', 'Husband', 'White', 'Male', 0, 0, 50, 'United-States', '<=50K']
```

I need to convert it into `ndarray`. I do it by using `numpy.array()` method. However, this method changes all my variables into str_: () type.

Could you help me how to overcome this problem? I would like to change this list of lists into 2d `ndarray` containing both integers and strings so that I could later on transform string them into numerical values.

Answer (score 1):

As @ouboros1 answered using `numpy.array(my_list, dtype=object)` helped
Thanks a lot for help!!